# Why is Jetty serving css with text/html content type

Tags: scala, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm using an embedded Jetty server in a Scalatra app. The issue is that it serves `css` files with `text/html` content type:

Here is the main method:

```
package yard.web

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext
import org.scalatra.servlet.ScalatraListener

object JettyMain {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val server = new Server(9080)
    val context: WebAppContext = new WebAppContext("src/main/webapp", "/")
    context.setServer(server)
    context.setInitParameter(ScalatraListener.LifeCycleKey, "yard.web.ScalatraBootstrap")
    context.addEventListener(new ScalatraListener())
    server.setHandler(context)

    server.start()

    println("Press ENTER to stop server")
    Console.readLine()
    server.stop()
    server.join()
  }
}
```

The file is located at `src/main/webapp/libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css`, and served with:

```
$ curl --head http://localhost:9080/libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Last-Modified: Sat, 06 Apr 2013 14:30:35 GMT
Content-Length: 127247
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Jetty(8.1.10.v20130312)
```

Why is Jetty thinking it's an html file?

---

Here is the `ScalatraBootstrap` class for completeness:

```
package yard.web

import org.scalatra.LifeCycle
import javax.servlet.ServletContext
import yard.Settings
import yard.db.Store

class ScalatraBootstrap extends LifeCycle {
  override def init(context: ServletContext) {

    val settings = Settings.default
    val db = Store(settings).db

    context mount (new MainServlet, "/")
  }
}
```

---

*Update*: Using a `ResourceHandler` causes the css to be served with correct content type. However, the app doesn't work :(

Comment: what versions of scala and scalatra are you using?

Comment: scala 2.10, scalatra 2.2

Comment: I made a simple app with your code, same versions, and a dummy controller. I can still see the correct content type returned, as well as get the requests routed to the main controller. It may be that the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CSS file is typically served from the `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet`.

Which is declared in the `etc/webdefault.xml` file in the distribution.

Since you are using embedded mode, you'll want to provide this manually by calling [WebAppContext.setDefaultsDescriptor(String)](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html#setDefaultsDescriptor%28java.lang.String%29) with the path to your `etc/webdefault.xml` file.

And finally, the mime types themselves are loaded by the `DefaultServlet` via the [`mime.properties`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-http/src/main/resources/org/eclipse/jetty/http/mime.properties?id=jetty-8.1.10.v20130312) file, which is loaded by Jetty via a call to `Classloader.getResource("/org/eclipse/jetty/http/mime.properties")`.

Note: the `mime.properties` file is found in the `jetty-http-8.1.10.v20130312.jar` file.

Comment: `mime.properties` is there and has the correct css line. I'm using sbt to manage the deps, btw. Using `ResourceHandler` fixes the content type, but I can't find a way to combine it with the `WebAppContext`. Also, I'm not actually using any `web.xml` file.

Comment: Doesn't matter that you have a `web.xml` or not.  The [webdefault.xml](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-webapp/src/main/config/etc/webdefault.xml?id=jetty-8.1.10.v20130312) is still required.  Grab yourself a copy of it, modify it to suit your needs (such as removing the jsp support), get a file reference to it, and set that file reference via `WebAppContext.setDefaultsDescriptor(String)`.  This is assuming that DefaultServlet is serving your CSS file.  It could be Scala itself serving the CSS, if so, you'll need to configure Scala.

Comment: you are correct. The problem was that Scala was serving the css. When I added a `web.xml` with the correct settings to have `default-servlet` serve them everything worked.